# Flash CS5 AS3 Mask with keyframe preventing bitmap loading

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a Flash app that loads a PNG as a bitmap and adds it to a MovieClip instance called `test_mc` on the stage. `test_mc` contains a placeholder clip that we hide after adding the bitmap. e.g

```
test_mc.addChild(bmp);
test_mc.placeholder.visible=0;
```

This works fine.

I then move the MovieClip around the stage in the timeline with a lot of keyframes.

This works fine.

I then add a layer, called layer_mask, above the layer with the movieclip on. I create a shape on layer_mask and set layer_mask to mask the movieclip's layer.

This still works fine.

Now I add a keyframe in `layer_mask`.

This stops working. The bmp is no longer loaded into the movieclip, and the placeholder is no longer hidden.

Can anyone shed any light on why that might be happening?

Thanks for your time.

UPDATE: The bitmap is actually loaded in and displayed correctly until the keyframe in the mask is hit, at which point it reverts to displaying the placeholder without the loaded bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. In case anyone else has this problem...

I had to make the mask shape into a movieclip and then use the shapes movieclip to add the keyfames onto. It's a little bit frustrating because you can't see what you are masking but at least it works.